# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, arduino

I am currently working on a project where I connect an arduino uno to a windows form and display the temperature in it using serial communication.
However I got this weird error every time I compiled my app

> **System.IndexOutOfRangeException:** 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I have declared my string array correctly. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?

[image: SERIAL COM ARDUINO (IMAGE)]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        public String[] towTemp = new string[1];
        public Task Tempdisplay()
            {
            //timer1.Start();
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    String tempFromArduino = serialPort1.ReadLine().ToString();
                    towTemp = tempFromArduino.Split(',');
                    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                    if (float.TryParse(towTemp[0], out float result1))
                    {
                    result1 = (float)(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(result1), 1));
                    label2.Text = result1.ToString();
                    aGauge1.Value = result1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (float.TryParse(towTemp[1], out float result2))
                    {
                    result2 = (float)(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(result2), 1));
                    label3.Text = result2.ToString();
                    aGauge2.Value = result2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }




                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                }
            });
            }

        private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer1.Interval = 1000;
           await Tempdisplay();



        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt matter how you declare it, you overwite the original array with this assignment: `towTemp = tempFromArduino.Split(',');`. If there is no comma in the string you will get this error at `towTemp[1]`

Comment: You can declare the array all you want but if you don't fill it (or the incoming data is not as you expected) you can get index out of bounds. Always check the index before accessing it

Comment: So what should i do to keep the old array and try to get the values from the arduino?

Comment: "*I have declared my string array correctly*". Do you realize that `new string[1];` creates an array with 1 element?

Comment: @gre_gor i have even made an array with 20 elements and its the same but i think i have corrected the issue

Answer (score 0):

With that line `towTemp = tempFromArduino.Split(',');` you overwrite the array that means it can have the length 0 now.

Check its length before you access it.

Comment: Please recheck the question i have added a screenshot of Serial COM and how values are being streamed to the windows app.

Comment: maybe you check the output to often and there is no new data, maybe try this:
`String tempFromArduino = serialPort1.ReadLine().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(tempFromArduino);
if(!tempfromArduino.Contains(","){return;}
towTemp = tempFromArduino.Split(',');`

Comment: i have tried this but know i am getting this error : System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'